# How to make a original controls in electrom frameless window in macOS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Some applications made with Electron, running at macOS, didn't have title. But we always can see some controls. How to make controls (original) in macOS applications?

(Electron) Like Typora,

[image: view image]

We can see some controls.

Answer (score 0):

I visited [Electron Docs(BrowserWindow)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window/) like **Typora**
Use this and paste it in the *main.js*

```js
if(platform == 'darwin') {
    mainWindow.setWindowButtonVisibility(true)
}
```